# Terraform .12 nested loop

Tags: terraform, terraform0.12+

variables.tf

```
variable "teams" {
  type        = map(any)
  default     = {}
}
```

input_value:

```
teams = {
    {
      team_id    = "abc"
      role_names = ["owner"]
    },
    {
      team_id    = "bcd"
      role_names = ["read", "write"]
    }
  }
}
```

main.tf:

```
resource "mongodbatlas_project" "project" {
  name   = "testing"
  org_id = "123456"
    dynamic "teams" {
        for_each = var.teams
    
        content {
          id    = teams.value.team_id
          names = [teams.value.role_names]
        }
      }
}
```

I have been trying the above code and it is not working. Is there an easier way to assign nested team value to the variable?

Answer (score 0):

The `teams` variable does not seem to be correct for me and there are syntax errors (e.g. extra `}`in `teams`). I think it should be `list`, not `map`:

```
variable "teams" {
  type        = list(any)
  default     = []
}
```

and then

```
teams = [
    {
      team_id    = "abc"
      role_names = ["owner"]
    },
    {
      team_id    = "bcd"
      role_names = ["read", "write"]
    }
  ]
```

Then your resource could be:

```
resource "mongodbatlas_project" "project" {

  name   = "testing"
  org_id = "123456"

  dynamic "teams" {
    for_each = toset(var.teams)
    
    content {
       id    = teams.value.team_id
       names = teams.value.role_names
    }
 }

}
```

When using [dynamic blocks](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/expressions.html#dynamic-blocks) the iterator is called same as the block name.